# Uploading new TestFlight builds after AppStore approval

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

I'm going to submit my app to AppStore soon. But I'm wondering if my beta testers will still be able to use new TestFlight builds and the build from AppStore simultaneously after approval (my app supports push notifications). Is it possible without two different bundle ids?

Is the only solution to uninstall AppStore version and install new from TestFlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible for them to use both. When the new TestFlight build is installed it will upgrade the AppStore version that is already installed. The user will be able to re-download the AppStore version and over-write the TestFlight version. One thing to be careful of is that the old version can still read any files written by the new version. E.g. if you changed the file format in the new version then re-installing the old version may cause it to have issues if it can't read the new file format.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought that manual uninstall will be necessary. Thanks for pointing out the problem with old data. I'll remember that.

Answer (score 0):

They will still be able to use the TestFlight builds. I believe they will have to uninstall the AppStore version.